# Using Closure Compiler on ES6 Modules with Properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, google-closure-compiler, es6-modules

So after a day of testing I'm almost there: using [google-closure-compiler-js](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-js) and [gulp.js](https://gulpjs.com/) to minify / compile my ES6 module based "library".

There is just one problem left. How to call the properties of an imported module?

My test case consists of 3 files:

**`gulpfile.js`**

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const compiler = require("google-closure-compiler-js").gulp();
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

gulp.task("default", function() {
// wildcards don't seem to work yet with the js version
// files need to be in reverse order of dependency...
return gulp.src(["src/boilerplate/main.js", "src/app.js"])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(compiler({
        jsOutputFile: "app.min.js",
        compilationLevel: "ADVANCED",
        warningLevel: "VERBOSE",
        createSourceMap: true
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("/"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
});
```

---

**`src/boilerplate/main.js`**

```
var mod = {};
export default mod;

var foo = "FOO";
var bar = "BAR";

function foobar(join) {
    join = (typeof join === "string") ? join : "";
    return foo + join + bar;
}
Object.defineProperty(mod, "foobar", {value: foobar});
```

---

**`src/app.js`**

```
import boilerplate from "./boilerplate/main.js";

console.log(boilerplate["foobar"]("+"));
console.log(boilerplate.foobar("+"));
```

---

If you log `boilerplate` here, you see that it has the property "foobar". Symbol intact and all. Great!

Hence app.js' first call – bracket notation ["foobar"] – works perfectly fine. However, the dot notation does not. Calls to an imported module's property get minified by Closure Compiler!
You get your classic "Hi. I'm new to ADVANCED mode" error: `TypeError: a.a is not a function`.

How do I prevent this? (& let's assume exporting foobar directly isn't viable, for real world's sake.)

- Do I need an exports file? How exactly would I do that? My first ventures in that direction did not take me far... is there a trick specific to [google-closure-compiler-js](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-js)?
- Is there some kind of hack that allows for dot notation, until Closure Compiler adds a feature that automatically does not rename calls to properties of imports?
- And what does this [closure-compiler/wiki](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/JS-Modules#type-references)'s article about *JS-Modules#type-references* advise me to do? Is this the answer I fail to implement?

  `/** @param {foo.Foo} Foo */
  function(Foo) {}`

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you using a `mod` object instead of just using a named export? That will, amongst other things, prevent treeshaking.

Comment: Why do you need `Object.defineProperty`? You can easily define your module in this way: `var mod = {foobar};`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder partly for that reason, to prevent treeshaking; if I want to create a library that's distributed in a minified version - that would be desirable?
And the other thing is, that I wanted to test how to actually export and access an object. Granted, it makes no sense here!, with the foobar function.

Comment: @Andy I could definitely do that! It's a relic from ES5, where defining it this way automatically made it non-enum, non-config, non-writable. With modules that should not be needed anymore. Good catch. :)

Comment: @JonasM.Schlatter: No, treeshaking is a good thing you want your library to enable. If an app using your lib doesn't need function X, treeshaking can leave function X out of the bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ADVANCED mode compatibility, use `Object.defineProperties` to avoid quoted strings.

```
Object.defineProperties(mod, {
  foobar: {value: foobar}
});
```

Anytime you use quoted strings, you will be required to use brackets (or other techniques) or risk violating the consistent property access rules.

Comment: Yes! Holy smokes. That was the missing piece. Thanks a thousand.